# Java docx4j hide text in docm/docx

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using 'docx4j' 3.1.0 version with Java 8 and I have a requirement to hide text while writing it into doc file.
How do I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and if you have problems try to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the wml structure of the doc file, I found out that doc has style field called Vanish which, I found from the docx4j source code, which is a method under the run properties object see the example below.

```
runProperties.setVanish(booleanDefaultTrue);
```

Full example for creating a hidden text with run is below.

```
public static R createHiddenTextRun(String data) {
        R run=factory.createR();
        RPr runProperties = new RPr();
        BooleanDefaultTrue booleanDefaultTrue = new BooleanDefaultTrue();
        runProperties.setVanish(booleanDefaultTrue);
        run.setRPr(runProperties);
        run.getContent().add(data);
        return run;
    }
```

Above I'm creating Run with Run properties which will hide the text we passed.